# Calculate and displays the sum of all numbers from 1 to 20

Tags: python, beginner

This is a beginner's class. I just need help verifying if this code is correct, or edit the parts that need fixing.

```
n = int(input("Enter a number"))
sum = 0
for i in range(1,n+1):
    sum = sum + i
    print("The sum is:", sum)
```

Answer (score 4):

### Bug?

Do you want to display a cumulative sum every time the loop executes? That's what you do now. If not - if you want to only display the final sum - you need to de-indent your `print`.

### Sum

You can do the whole sum using the actual `sum` function, like this:

```
total = sum(range(1, n + 1))
```

Note that you should not call a variable `sum`, because that shadows the built-in `sum` function.

### Calculating the sum

This doesn't actually need a loop or a call to `sum` at all. Math will tell you that the entire sum will evaluate to \$n(n + 1)/2\$; an example of equivalence:

$$
\begin{align}
1 + 2 &= 3\\
\frac{2 * 3}{2} &= 3
\end{align}
$$

Comment: The generator expression is unnecessary.  Simply sum the range: `total = sum(range(1, n + 1))`.

Comment: @AJNeufeld nice!

Comment: A '[graphical proof](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gau%C3%9Fsche_Summenformel#/media/Datei:Gau%C3%9Fsche_Summenformel_geometrisch.svg)' of sum(1 to n) = n(n+1)/2